# XSL-FO Serial in the Header

Tags: xsl-fo

### Input XML:

```
<Data>
    <BPP>
        <CP>A</CP>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>A</CP>
        <Name>Show</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>B</CP>
        <Name>Cunny</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>D</CP>
        <Name>Johny</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>C</CP>
        <Name>Bunny</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>B</CP>
        <Name>Sunny</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>C</CP>
        <Name>Neha</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>D</CP>
        <Name>Josh</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>B</CP>
        <Name>Ash</Name>
    </BPP>
    <BPP>
        <CP>A</CP>
        <Name>Isha</Name>
    </BPP>
</Data>
```

### My Code In XSL-FO:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid">
<fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="25%"/>
<fo:table-body>
<!-- Repeatable row-->
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid">
            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Header</fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid">
            **<fo:block font-weight="bold"><!--Serial Value of 'A' or 'B'--></fo:block>**
        </fo:table-cell>

        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid">
            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select='Data/BPP/Name'/></fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid">
            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select='Data/BPP/CP'/></fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

### My requirement:

if **Data/BPP/CP='A' or Data/BPP/CP='B'**
then in **Each row, 2nd column** of the table **serial number** should be displayed
The resultant output has to be in the following table format

### Header 1

Joe         A

---

### Header 2

Show        A

---

### Header 3

Cunny       B

---

### Header 4

Sunny       B

---

### Header 5

Ash     B

---

### Header 6

Isha        A

---

How to achieve the above serial number for 'A' or 'B'(not for 'C','D' etc)? i've tried to get this with **xslt** but i failed. Any help either with **xslt or xsl-fo** regarding this is really Commendable..

Comment: It is indeed easiest to use a language like XSLT to generate the XSL-FO you need to get the desired output. Would you mind sharing your XSLT attempt with us? That would allow us to help you improve it. Best way of learning..

Comment: sorry i don't mind in sharing XSLT but, Can you please start from scartch! it is preferable i think becoz, the xslt code i've done is of no use as i'm naive to xslt, it won't help you much in making modifications. so, can you guys please provide a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean be 'serial value of A or B'? Do you want to display 'serial number' when it's A or B, and otherwise just the value (i.e. C, D, ...)?

Comment: @Peter, My requirement is to display the content of only A or B with Serial Number in the Header. Please don't bother about C,D,... Thanks if somebody suggest me the way to solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this, but try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/BPP[./CP = 'A' or ./CP = 'B']">
    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

(I edited away my previous answer, as it was wrong. I now understand your question)

The above XSL will select all BPP nodes where CP is A or is B. The `position()` will output the position of the current node. I'm just not sure if it will output the position of the node in the entire node list, or in the result of our for-each.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, But your answer nowhere related to serializing the contents of A or B. i need the stuff which you have commented.. The stuff which numerically displays the content related to A or B..  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Explain exactly what you mean by 'serializing the contents of A or B'.

Comment: In my XSL-FO document, i need to display "Header #" as Header. where '#' --> is the number which signifies the occurence of A or B( excludes C,D,..) in Data/BPP/CP as shown in Input XML above. I hope you get my query now